# Удаление первых символов JS(TS)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Задача: У нас есть предложения

```
1. Database: Database
2. Back-end: Requests GitHub
3. UX/UI: Make footer
```

Нам нужно удалить первое слово, две точки и пробел, то есть у нас есть

```
"UX/UI: Make footer" => "Make footer"
"Back-end: Requests GitHub" => "Requests GitHub"
"Database: Database" => "Database"
```

Как это можно сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Какие-то попытки были?

Comment: Я решил. replace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нам нужно удалить первое слово, две точки и пробел ... Как это можно сделать?

Например вот так... Такая регулярка явно меньше чем у тебя в решении. ;)

```js
const test = s => s.split(': ').slice(1).join(': ')

console.log(test('UX/UI: Make footer'))
console.log(test('Back-end: Requests GitHub'))
console.log(test('Database: Database'))
```

Вот вариант с регуляркой...

```js
const str = `1. Database: Database
2. Back-end: Requests GitHub
3. UX/UI: Make footer`
const r = /[a-z-\/]+:\s/ig
const s = str.replace(r, '')
console.log(s)
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ тоже подходит!

Answer (score 0):

Я решил через

```
const regExp = /\*|Full-stack:|Back-end:|Front-end:|NoBilling:|Development:|Database:|UX\/UI:|\$/g;
let handlertText = getText.replace(regExp, '')
```

Comment: Посмотри мой вариант с регуляркой. Со своей ты дюже перемудрил...

Comment: Решение неустойчивое: при добавлении очередного первого символа придётся модифицировать это регулярное выражение.

Comment: Если будет добавлен символ я сразу увижу ошибку.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38WpD.png

Comment: Как мы видим, если что-то пошло не так я сразу увижу Error и можно исправить. У меня идёт интеграция с github https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y1XZ.png. И как мы видим я просто в githube даю понять что будет отображаться на страницы.

Comment: Спросони только сейчас понял, что возможно не мне адресовано :D